# section box is overlapping on top of another section on mobile view and footer is stuck in the middle on mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries, mobile-website

Two problem i am currently facing here in my code. Section "services_offered" is overlapping on top of section "description" in mobile device view. Section "footer" is stuck in the middle  in mobile device view. Could you please spot my mistake and give me better solution. i was expecting the footer to be at the bottom, when viewed in mobile view.
and section description and section services not overlapping

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById('navLinks');

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "0";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* HOME PAGE */


/* section header */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(images/background1.jpg);
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1% 2%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.header nav a {
  background-color: transparent;
}

nav img {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav_links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav_links ul {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav_links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav_links ul li a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.text_box {
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.text_box h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding-top: 130px;
}

.text_box p {
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.text_box .need_website {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.hero_btn {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 12px 34px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: gray;
}

.hero_btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background: #ff0000;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

nav .fa {
  display: none;
}


/* description header */

.description {
  width: 80%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: justify;
  z-index: 2;
}

.description h4 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

.description p {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-indent: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
}


/* section services_offered */

.services_offered {
  width: 90%;
  height: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.services_offered h4 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
}

.services_offered .services_home_page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.services_home_page div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 18px #dae0e5;
}

.services_home_page div h3 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 40px;
}

.services_home_page div img {
  width: 200px;
}

.services_home_page div p {
  color: #888888;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.click_on_service {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* section footer */

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #454547;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  position: bottom;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.social_media_links {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.social_media_links a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.fa-twitter {
  color: #00acee;
}

.fa-instagram {
  color: #cd486b;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  color: #0A66C2;
}

.fa-facebook,
.fa-twitter,
.fa-instagram,
.fa-linkedin {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.copyright {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer p,
a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 450;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media(max-width:700px) {
  .text_box h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 180px;
  }
  .text_box p {
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
  .nav_links ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav_links {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }
  nav .fa {
    display: block;
    color: gray;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav_links ul {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="">
      <img src="images/brighttechnoinfra.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="nav_links" id="navLinks">
      <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="demo.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">INFRA SUPPLIES</a></li>
        <li><a href="about_us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
  </nav>
  <div class="text_box">
    <h1>WELCOME to <br>BightTTechnoInfra firm.</h1>
    <p>"Bright your atmosphere with techno projects."</p>
    <p class="need_website">need infrastructure setup?</p>
    <a href="tel:+9100000000" class="hero_btn">Call us now</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="description">
  <h4>Why Choose 'US'?</h4>
  <p>
    BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA is a leading infrastructure supplies company committed to delivering cutting-edge solutions to support economic growth, enhance living standards, and promote sustainable development. With a track record of excellence and innovation,
    BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA has become a trusted partner for governments, private enterprises, and communities alike. Our Comprehensive Product Range: At BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA, we offer a comprehensive range of infrastructure supplies that cater to various sectors
    and industries. Our product portfolio includes:
    <br> 1. Energy Infrastructure: BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA is at the forefront of delivering sustainable energy solutions. Our products include solar panels, UPS, and advanced energy storage systems that enable the transition to cleaner and more reliable energy
    sources.
    <br> 2. Telecommunications: Our telecommunications infrastructure supplies cover cutting-edge networking equipment, fiber optic cables, and communication towers, enabling seamless connectivity and improved information exchange.
    <br> 3. Urban Development: BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA contributes to well-planned urban development with our range of products for housing, construction, and smart city initiatives. From modern building materials to smart technologies, we support the creation
    of sustainable and livable urban environments.
    <br>
    <br> Our Commitment to Quality and Sustainability: Quality and sustainability are at the core of everything we do at BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA. We adhere to strict industry standards and work with reputable manufacturers to ensure that our products meet or
    exceed expectations. Furthermore, we actively seek environmentally-friendly solutions, promoting eco-conscious practices across our supply chain. Collaborative Approach: BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA takes a collaborative approach to every project. We work closely
    with our clients to understand their unique needs and tailor solutions accordingly. Our team of experts is committed to providing professional guidance, technical expertise, and ongoing support throughout the project lifecycle. Building a Brighter
    Future: As a company, we take pride in contributing to the development of infrastructure that positively impacts societies and economies. At BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA, our vision is to build a brighter future, where sustainable infrastructure forms the foundation
    for progress and prosperity. Choose BRIGHTTECHNOINFRA as your partner for infrastructure supplies, and together, we'll pave the way towards a more connected, resilient, and sustainable world.
  </p>
</section>

<section class="services_offered">
  <h4>We offer Infrastructure Supplies on</h4>
  <div class="services_home_page">


    <div>
      <h3>AGRICULTURE</h3>
      <img src="images/agriculture.png" alt="">
      <p>"Agriculture infrastructure supplies are essential components that support the agricultural sector and play a crucial role in ensuring food security, sustainable farming practices, and rural development. These supplies encompass a wide range of
        products and equipment that aid farmers and agricultural communities in their daily operations."</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>EDUCATION</h3>
      <img src="images/education.png" alt="">
      <p>"Educational infrastructure supplies are crucial elements in supporting the educational sector, ensuring a conducive learning environment, and promoting effective teaching and learning. These supplies encompass a wide range of materials and equipment
        that facilitate the functioning of educational institutions and enhance the overall educational experience."</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>OFFICE</h3>
      <img src="images/OFFICE.png" alt="">
      <p>"As an office infrastructure supplies provider, our company aims to create functional, efficient, and aesthetically pleasing workspaces for businesses of all sizes. We understand that the right office environment can significantly impact employee
        productivity, collaboration, and overall well-being."</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>PUBLIC</h3>
      <img src="images/public.jpg" alt="">
      <p>"As a provider of public infrastructure supplies, our company is dedicated to delivering high-quality and reliable solutions that contribute to the development and well-being of communities. At our company, we offer a comprehensive range of public
        infrastructure supplies, tailored to meet the diverse needs of governments, municipalities, and public authorities."</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <img src="images/home.jpg" alt="">
      <p>"House infrastructure supplies are essential for creating safe, comfortable, and functional living spaces. As a provider of these supplies, the focus is on offering high-quality products and exceptional customer service to meet the diverse needs
        of homeowners, contractors, and builders."</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="click_on_service" href="services.html">Click here to read more.....</a>
</section>

<section class="footer">
  <p>For any questions or clarifications, please email or contact us.</p>

  <div class="social_media_links">
    <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>
  <p>&copy Copyright 2023 - BrightTechnoInfra PVT LTD | All Rights Reserved</p>
  <p>Developed by <a href="Tunnel Vision">xyz</a></p>
</section>
```

Comment: Setting a fixed height for sections like `description` and `services_offered` is a bad idea. The height of these sections has to be flexible and adapt to the width of the screen.

Comment: thank a lot. that helped me to solve one issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's just that you are putting height on each section that causes the overlapping issue. just remove the height and it looks fine as you wanted.

Hope it helps

```
.description {
  width: 80%;
  padding-top: 2rem;
  margin: auto;
}
.services_offered {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.services_offered .services_home_page {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #454547;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).